Concatenar en el input los valores de cada boton que apreto
Tengo el siguiente codigo, mi calculadora funciona perfectamente cuando uno va ingresando valores por el input; todos los test funcionan muy bien. Ahora, mi problema viene cuando agrego los botones ya sean para la suma y otros operadores, numeros, el boton de igualdad, etc...
Mi tema es que, al hacer el test con vitest de cada click de cada boton este directamente reemplaza el valor del input y no lo concatena, es decir, yo clickeo primero en 1 entonces en mi input deberia salir "1", luego yo clickeo el 2 entonces deberia salir en mi input el "12". Bueno, esto es todo lo contrario, primero sale el "1" y si apreto el 2 sale el "2", es decir, no se concatenan. No se como hacer para aplicar esta concatenacion sin afectar los test anteriores. Hice muchos intentos con el setOp(prevValue => preValue + Value) pero siempre falla y falla...
export function useEntryInput(){
  const [ op, setOp ] = useState('');
  
  const refreshValue = (newValue) => {
    setOp(newValue);
    // me falta hacer que al ir clickeando se vaya concatenando los valores
    // Tengo que verificar en el isFirstAns o aca, de que si "newValue" empieza con "ans", este se le
    // ponga al inicio de toda la cadena.
  }


  const isFirstAns = (newValue, isFirst) => {
    if(!isFirst && (newValue[0] !== '.' && isNaN(newValue[0]))){
      let ans = 'Ans' + newValue + '_';
      return ans;
    }
    return newValue.concat('_');
  }

  return { op, refreshValue, isFirstAns, resetValue};
}

export function useFormResult({ op }){
    let newValue;
  const [ result, setResult ] = useState('0');
    let isFirstResult = useRef(true);
  const [ error, setError ] = useState(null);

  if(op.startsWith('Ans')){
    newValue = op.slice(3, -1);
  } else newValue = op.slice(0, -1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isFirstResult.current){
      isFirstResult.current = false;
      return;
    }

    if(newValue.trim().length === 0){
      return;
    }

    if(newValue.length === 1 && newValue === '.'){
      setResult('0');
      return;
    }

    if(newValue.includes('/0') || newValue.includes('/.')){
      setError('Syntax Error');
      return
    }

    if(newValue.includes('.')){
      newValue = newValue.replace('+.', '+0.');
      newValue = newValue.replace('-.', '-0.');
      newValue = newValue.replace('*.', '*0.');
      newValue = newValue.replace('/.', '/0.');
      newValue = newValue.replace('Ans.', 'Ans0.');
      newValue = newValue.replace(/^\./, `0.`);
    }
  
  }, [op]);

  const updateResult = () => {
    try {
      let newRes;
      if(!isNaN(newValue[0])){
        newRes = newValue;
      } else newRes = result + newValue;
      setResult(evaluate(newRes));
      isFirstResult.current = false;
    } catch(e) {
      setError('Syntax Error');
    }
  }

  return { result, updateResult, error, isFirst: isFirstResult.current };
}

//==================================== COMPONENTES ====================================
//====================================             ====================================


//==================================== PRINCIPAL ====================================
//====================================           ====================================

function App(){
  const Keyboard = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'AC', '+', '-', '*', '/', '.'];
  const { op, refreshValue, isFirstAns, resetValue } = useEntryInputSpy();
  const { result, updateResult, error, isFirst } = useFormResultSpy({ op });

  const handleValue = (event) => {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    let op = isFirstAns(inputValue, isFirst);
    refreshValue(op);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    updateResult();
  }
  
  const handleButton = (event) => {
    const inputValue = event.target.textContent;
    let op = isFirstAns(inputValue, isFirst);
    refreshValue(op);
  }

  return (
    <>
    <form role="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type='text' onChange={handleValue} value={error ? error : op} placeholder='_'/>
      <input type='text' data-testid='Resultado' value={result} placeholder="0" readOnly/>
      <button data-testid={'='}>=</button>
    </form>

    {
      Keyboard.map(valueKey => (
        <button data-testid={valueKey} onClick={handleButton}>{valueKey}</button>
      ))
    }
    </>
  );
}

MIS TESTS
describe('Calculadora - por teclado', () => {
  beforeEach(
    cleanup,
    vi.clearAllMocks,
    vi.resetAllMocks
  );

  let inputEntryValue, inputResultValue;
  const initialRender = () => {
    render(<App />);
    inputEntryValue = screen.getByPlaceholderText('_');
    inputResultValue = screen.getByTestId('Resultado');
  }

  // test.each(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','8', '9', 'AC', '+', '-', '*', '/', '=', '.'])
  // ('Deberia renderizar correctamente el boton %s', (valueButton) => {
  //   initialRender();
  //   expect( screen.getByTestId(`${valueButton}`) ).toBeTruthy();
  // });

  test('Deberia retonar los valores iniciales si no ingreso nada', () => {
    initialRender();
    const buttonIgual = screen.getByTestId('=');
    fireEvent.click(buttonIgual);
    expect( inputEntryValue.value ).toEqual('');
    expect( inputResultValue.value ).toEqual('0');
  });

  test('Deberia dar error si inicialmente multiplico o divido', () => {
    initialRender();
    const buttonPor = screen.getByTestId('*');
    const buttonDiv = screen.getByTestId('/');
    const buttonIgual = screen.getByTestId('=');

    fireEvent.click(buttonPor);
    fireEvent.click(buttonIgual);
    expect( inputEntryValue.value ).toEqual('Syntax Error');

    fireEvent.click(buttonDiv);
    fireEvent.click(buttonIgual);
    expect( inputEntryValue.value ).toEqual('Syntax Error');
  });

  test('Deberia dar error dividir por cero', () => {
    initialRender();

    const buttonUno = screen.getByTestId('1');
    const buttonDiv = screen.getByTestId('/');
    const buttonCero = screen.getByTestId('0');
    const buttonIgual = screen.getByTestId('=');

    fireEvent.click(buttonUno);
    fireEvent.click(buttonDiv);
    fireEvent.click(buttonCero);
    fireEvent.click(buttonIgual);
    expect( inputEntryValue.value ).toEqual('Syntax Error');

  });
});

